# Strange \n in base64 encoded string in Ruby

Tags: ruby, base64, encode

The inbuilt Base64 library in Ruby is adding some '\n's. I'm unable to find out the reason. For this special example:

```
irb(main):001:0> require 'rubygems'
=> true
irb(main):002:0> require 'base64'
=> true
irb(main):003:0> str =  "1110--ad6ca0b06e1fbeb7e6518a0418a73a6e04a67054"
=> "1110--ad6ca0b06e1fbeb7e6518a0418a73a6e04a67054"
irb(main):004:0> Base64.encode64(str)
=> "MTExMC0tYWQ2Y2EwYjA2ZTFmYmViN2U2NTE4YTA0MThhNzNhNmUwNGE2NzA1\nNA==\n"
```

The \n's are at the last and 6th position from end. The decoder (Base64.decode64) returns back the old string perfectly. Strange thing is, these \n's don't add any value to the encoded string. When I remove the newlines from the output string, the decoder decodes it again perfectly.

```
irb(main):005:0> Base64.decode64(Base64.encode64(str).gsub("\n", '')) == str
=> true
```

More of this, I used an another JS library to produce the base64 encoded output of the same input string, the output comes without the \n's.

Is this a bug or anything else? Has anybody faced this issue before?

FYI,

```
$ ruby -v
ruby 1.8.7 (2008-08-11 patchlevel 72) [i486-linux]
```

Comment: same weird problem here

Answer (score 284, accepted):

**Edit:** Since I wrote this answer [`Base64.strict_encode64()`](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/3.0.0/Base64.html#method-i-strict_encode64) was added, which does not add newlines.

---

[The docs](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/base64/rdoc/classes/Base64.html) are somewhat confusing, the `b64encode` method is supposed to add a newline for every 60th character, and the example for the `encode64` method is actually using the `b64encode` method.

It seems the `pack("m")` method for the Array class used by `encode64` also adds the newlines. I would consider it a design bug that this is not optional.

You could either remove the newlines yourself, or if you're using rails, there's [ActiveSupport::CoreExtensions::Base64::Encoding](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/CoreExtensions/Base64/Encoding.html) with the `encode64s` method.

Comment: Seems that since i wrote this answer there is now `strict_encode64()` which ostensibly does not add newlines.

Comment: So dumb! Why you do this to me, Ruby?

Comment: This is an assinie default, but as @ChristofferHammarström mentions, there's a way to get a true b64 encoding now.

Comment: Apparently this exists to maintain backwards compat with software that cannot handle long lines. https://stackoverflow.com/a/20065991/5749914

Answer (score 124):

In ruby-1.9.2 you have Base64.strict_encode64 which doesn't add that \n (newline) at the end.

Comment: That's a much easier solution!

Comment: I have checked Base64.strict_encode64  is not properly encoded three character string. like Base64.strict_encode64('abc') -> YWJj . 
the above example is not encoded correctly.

Comment: @CodeMaker I thought `YWJj` is correct. What's wrong with that?

Answer (score 14):

Use `strict_encode64` method. `encode64` adds \n every 60 symbols

Comment: can we change it to add after 76 symbols ?

Answer (score 9):

Yeah, this is quite normal. The [doc](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/base64/rdoc/classes/Base64.html#M000005) gives an example demonstrating the line-splitting. base64 does the same thing in other languages too (eg. Python).

The reason content-free newlines are added at the encode stage is because base64 was originally devised as an encoding mechanism for sending binary content in e-mail, where the line length is limited. Feel free to replace them away if you don't need them.

Comment: This just happened in my Android App (Java's Base64 library). I was totally confused with this strange occuring. Took me literally 1 hour to figure out what's wrong and then searched for the error. This comment is helping understand legacy issues even after 6 years.

Answer (score 6):

Seems they've got to be stripped/ignored, like:

```
Base64.encode64(str).gsub(/\n/, '')
```

Comment: This solution is dirty.. anythein else?

Comment: @yaauie ([via suggested edit](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/6210102)): Edits that make a substantial change should generally not be done.  I'd recommend posting that as a separate answer.

Answer (score 2):

The `\n` added when using `Base64#encode64` is correct, check this post out: https://glaucocustodio.github.io/2014/09/27/a-reminder-about-base64encode64-in-ruby/