# Spotify Web API Bad Request Error "invalid_client" when refreshing token

Tags: ruby-on-rails, spotify, httparty

I'm building an app in Rails using the Spotify web API. I built a method to refresh a user's token, but am receiving a 400 error. According the the Spotify Web API docs, the header of my request needs to be in the following format:

```
Authorization: Basic <base64 encoded client_id:client_secret>
```

Using Httparty gem, here's the POST method to refresh the access token:

```
def refresh_token
client_id = "foo"
client_secret = "bar"
client_id_and_secret = Base64.encode64("#{client_id}:#{client_secret}")
result = HTTParty.post(
    "https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token",
    :body => {:grant_type => "refresh_token",
              :refresh_token => "#{self.oauth_refresh_token}"},
    :headers => {"Authorization" => "Basic #{client_id_and_secret}"}
    )
end
```

Here's what "result" ends up being:

```
=> #<HTTParty::Response:0x7f92190b2978 parsed_response={"error"=>"invalid_client", "error_description"=>"Invalid client secret"}, @response=#<Net::HTTPBadRequest 400 Bad Request readbody=true>, @headers={"server"=>["nginx"], "date"=>["Sun, 31 Aug 2014 22:28:38 GMT"], "content-type"=>["application/json"], "content-length"=>["70"], "connection"=>["close"]}>
```

I can decode client_id_and_secret and it returns "foo:bar", so I'm at a loss as to why I'm receiving a 400 error. Any insight is much appreciated.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Found the issue... it was with the Base64 encoding in Ruby. Apparently (as shown in [Strange \n in base64 encoded string in Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2620975/strange-n-in-base64-encoded-string-in-ruby)) using the Base64.encode64('') method adds an extra line within the code. Using Base64.strict_encode64('') solved the issue.

Updated code:

```
def refresh_token
client_id = "foo"
client_secret = "bar"
client_id_and_secret = Base64.strict_encode64("#{client_id}:#{client_secret}")
result = HTTParty.post(
    "https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token",
    :body => {:grant_type => "refresh_token",
              :refresh_token => "#{self.oauth_refresh_token}"},
    :headers => {"Authorization" => "Basic #{client_id_and_secret}"}
    )
end
```