# check if string is base64

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, base64

i may recieve these two strings:

```
    base = Base64.encode64(File.open("/home/usr/Desktop/test", "rb").read)
    => "YQo=\n"

    string = File.open("/home/usr/Desktop/test", "rb").read
    => "a\n"
```

what i have tried so far is to check string with regular expression i-e. `/([A-Za-z0-9+\/]{4})*([A-Za-z0-9+\/]{4}|[A-Za-z0-9+\/]{3}=|[A-Za-z0-9+\/]{2}==$)/` but this would be very heavy if the file is big.

I also have tried `base.encoding.name` and `string.encoding.name` but both returns the same.

I have also seen [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8571501/how-to-check-whether-the-string-is-base64-encoded-or-not) and got regular expression solution but any other solution ?

Any idea ? I just want to get is the string is actually text or base64 encoded text....

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to check whether the string is base64 encoded or not](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8571501/how-to-check-whether-the-string-is-base64-encoded-or-not)

Comment: please read the question again i have updated. i have already seen that post

Comment: "but this would be very heavy if the file is big." Unfortunately, there is no other way to know. Is this sentence valid English skagpoople? You don't know until you find something in it that tells you it isn't. This is not the same "encoding" that `String#encoding` reports - that is character encoding, not file format that you are interested in.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use something like this, not very performant but you are guaranteed not to get false positives:

```
require 'base64'

def base64?(value)
  value.is_a?(String) && Base64.strict_encode64(Base64.decode64(value)) == value
end
```

The use of `strict_encode64` versus `encode64` prevents Ruby from inadvertently inserting newlines if you have a long string. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2621023/515584) for details.

Comment: You may want to use `strict_encode64` if you have a long string to avoid Ruby from inserting newlines inadvertently. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/2621023/515584 for details.

Comment: Using `strict_encode64` is definitely the right choice

Comment: `Base64.encode64` not work, using `strict_encode64`