# Ruby Base64 check if it's encoded

Tags: ruby, string, encoding, base64

I know I can translate any binary data into purely printable characters with `Base64.encode64` and translate it back to binary data with `Base64.decode64`.

But is there any way to check if the data is translated into printable characters with `Base64.encode64`??

For instance, I'm looking for something like the code below.

```
str = Base64.encode("test")
p str.encoded? #=> true
```

https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.3/libdoc/base64/rdoc/Base64.html

Comment: You're asking if there's a way to confirm that the output of `Base64.encode` consists only of printable characters? Base64, [by definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64), consists only of printable characters.

Comment: @anothermh Sorry for the confusion. I guess what I'm asking here is if there is any way to differentiate a normal printable string like `"test"` from a printable string that was originally binary and got translated into a printable string using `Base64encode64`.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8571501/3784008) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30476873/3784008) answer this question thoroughly, and are easily found by searching.