# HTTParty error 400: Invalid header name on simple GET request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, http, azure, get, httparty

Despite it being relatively simple, my brain can't comprehend new concepts all that easily so here I am.

I am using HTTParty to interact with the Microsoft Azure API. Here's an example of how their GET should look:

```
GET https://api.datamarket.azure.com/data.ashx/amla/text-analytics/v1/GetSentiment?Text=hello+world
```

Here's the headers they ask to be included:

```
Authorization: Basic <creds>
Accept: application/json

Where <creds> = ConvertToBase64(“AccountKey:” + yourActualAccountKey);
```

Here's my HTTParty class:

```
  def self.sentiment(phrase)
    require 'base64'
    key = "MYKEYWASHERE"
    accountKey = Base64.encode64("AccountKey:" + key)
    response = get("https://api.datamarket.azure.com/data.ashx/amla/text-analytics/v1/GetSentiment?Text=hello+world", :headers => { "Authorization" => "Basic " + accountKey, "Accept" => "application/json"})
    if response
        return response
    end
  end
```

It responds with:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN""http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd"> <HTML><HEAD><TITLE>Bad Request</TITLE> <META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" Content="text/html; charset=us-ascii"></HEAD> <BODY><h2>Bad Request - Invalid Header</h2> <hr><p>HTTP Error 400. The request has an invalid header name.</p> </BODY></HTML>
```

I also debugged it and it printed out the following:

```
opening connection to api.datamarket.azure.com:443...
opened
starting SSL for api.datamarket.azure.com:443...
SSL established
<- "GET /data.ashx/amla/text-analytics/v1/GetSentiment?Text=hello+world HTTP/1.1\r\nAuthorization: Basic QWNj(...)VREUmk1aWdudXRtL2VN\nak(...)R\r\nAccept: application/json\r\nConnection: close\r\nHost: api.datamarket.azure.com\r\n\r\n"
```

Anything obvious that I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

You have a strange `\n` character inside of the base64 encoded basic Authorization header. I really don't know how a `Base64.encode64()` can generate an LF character, you should investigate that. This breaks the HTTp query (you have a new header starting at `ak(...)` just after the LF (`\n`) character.

But be careful also not to print debug informations in stack overflow questions with the real base64 encoded key, this encoding is **just an encoding**, the contant is in clear text in you re-encode it to any charset, so your API key is made public. If you can re-ask for an API key.

**Edit** the ruby base64 encoding `\n` error is already known on stack overflo, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2621023/550618) for details on the `\n` added after 60 characters.

Comment: Hi Regilero, thanks for editing my question and giving me an answer. Cheers mate.

Comment: yep, but request a new key anyway.