# Equivalent of openssl_public_encrypt PHP function in Ruby

Tags: php, ruby, php-openssl

I would like to obtain an equivalent of the code below in ruby:

```
$key = '-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
some public key
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----';

$cc_number = '4242424242424242';
openssl_public_encrypt($cc_number, $cc_number_encrypted, $key);
echo base64_encode($cc_number_encrypted);
```

I tried:

```
pkey = '-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
some public key
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----'

cc = '4242424242424242'
key = OpenSSL::PKey::RSA.new(pkey)
puts Base64.encode64(key.public_encrypt(cc))
```

but it doesn't work.
How to write this PHP code in Ruby?

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution inspired by this question: [Strange \n in base64 encoded string in Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2620975/strange-n-in-base64-encoded-string-in-ruby).

I had to change:

```
puts Base64.encode64(key.public_encrypt(cc))
```

to

```
puts Base64.strict_encode64(key.public_encrypt(cc))
```

As the [documentation](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.4.0/libdoc/base64/rdoc/Base64.html#method-i-strict_encode64) says:

> This method complies with RFC 4648. No line feeds are added.