# Spotify Web API: Basic authorization

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, http, httprequest, rest-client

I need to get an access token from **Spotify Web API**. Based on [this documentation](https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/authorization-guide/#client-credentials-flow) I wrote the following method:

```
def authorize
  grant = Base64.encode64("#{SPOTIFY_KEY}:#{SPOTIFY_SECRET}")
  RestClient::Request.execute(
    method: :post,
    url: 'https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token',
    params: {'grant_type' => 'client_credentials'},
    headers: {"Authorization" => "Basic #{grant}","Accept" => "*/*; q=0.5, application/json"}
  )
end
```

and the following RSpec test:

```
it 'authorize' do
  obj = SpotifyIntegration.new
  response = obj.authorize
  myjson = JSON.parse(response.body)
  expect(myjson.has_key?('access_token')).to be(true)
  expect(myjson.has_key?('token_type')).to be(true)
  expect(myjson['token_type']).to eq('bearer')
  expect(myjson.has_key?('expires_in')).to be(true)
end
```

It happens that when I run this test, generating this request (caught with RESTCLIENT_LOG=stdout)

> RestClient.post "https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token", "Accept"=>"*/*; q=0.5, application/json", "Accept-Encoding"=>"gzip, deflate", "Authorization"=>"Basic Y2NmNTI3ODVlZWI1NDVlODk0ZmM2ZTY3YTZhNDM0ZDA6YTQ5MjdlOGFmOWQy\nNGE0OTgyZDRkODI1MmJhZjBkNTI=\n"

I get

> => 400 BadRequest | application/json 131 bytes

And it seems it is really a bad request, because I see no sign of the `grant_type => client_credentials`. The documentaions says this is mandadory **as a request body parameter**.

I believe I am sending this the wrong way, but I don't know how to to it correctly.

I tried to use `RestClient#post` instead of `RestClient::Request#execute`, doing this:

```
def authorize
  grant = Base64.encode64("#{SPOTIFY_KEY}:#{SPOTIFY_SECRET}")
  RestClient.post 'https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token', {'grant_type' => 'client_credentials'}.to_json, {"Authentication" => "Basic #{grant}",content_type: :json, accept: :json}
end
```

but then I got:

> RestClient::UnsupportedMediaType:
>          415 Unsupported Media Type

How may I send a request body parameter using `RestClient` gem?

Comment: Sure. I did that. With `{'grant_type' => 'client_credentials'}` I get a `400 Bad Request`. If I do it with `{'grant_type' => 'client_credentials'}.to_json` as I found in some references, I get a `415 Unsupported Media Type`...

Comment: Agreed, @Anthony. And this is why I am surprised it doesn't work. Don't really know what to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is the way Base64 is encoding the string which includes newlines that most OAuth2 providers don't accept.  You can do this instead:

```
grant = Base64.encode64("#{client_id}:#{client_secret}").delete("\n")

resp = RestClient.post('https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token',
                       {'grant_type' => 'client_credentials'},
                       {"Authorization" => "Basic #{grant}"})
```

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2621023/3109182) answer, new lines are added every 60 characters (that is news to me).  You can use another method that does not include newlines such as `strict_encode`...

```
grant = Base64.strict_encode64("#{client_id}:#{client_secret}")
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not exactly the answer you're looking for, but you should definitively take a look at this Ruby Library: [rspotify](https://github.com/guilhermesad/rspotify#rails--oauth). Spotify Oauthentication is very easy to do with it.

Comment: I know. But my project requires me to build this and I can't use an external gem. But thanks for your suggestion!