# React Native Fetch Blob multipart data image upload not putting any data in the request

Tags: react-native, image-uploading, multipartform-data, react-native-fetch-blob

I am trying to work out how to upload multiple images with RNFetchBlob. I'm using a base64 encoded version of an image as a test. Here's my request:

```
    const base64ImageData = "/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/2wCEAAkGBwgHBgkIBwgKCgkLDRYPDQwM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\ndVlRjOisOcENpVo9GkAX7eWAP//Z\n"
    const imgSrc = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + base64ImageData;

    RNFetchBlob.fetch('POST', 'http://localhost:3000/test_upload', {
      Authorization : "Bearer access-token",
      otherHeader : "foo",
      'Content-Type' : 'multipart/form-data',
    }, [
      // element with property `filename` will be transformed into `file` in form data
      { name : 'one', filename : 'testimage.jpeg', data: imgSrc},
      // custom content type
      { name : 'two', filename : 'testimage.jpeg', data: base64ImageData},

    ]).then((resp) => {
      console.log(resp)
    }).catch((err) => {
      console.log(err)
    })
```

And here's what my server receives as the request body:

```
"--RNFetchBlob218752\r\n" +
    "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"one\"; filename=\"testimage.jpeg\"\r\n" +
    "Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n" +
    "\r\n" +
    "\r\n" +
    "--RNFetchBlob218752\r\n" +
    "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"two\"; filename=\"testimage.jpeg\"\r\n" +
    "Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n" +
    "\r\n" +
    "\r\n" +
    "--RNFetchBlob218752--\r\n"
```

So the question is where has the image data gone?

(Note that the base64 string definitely works because I've displayed it in my demo app in an Image tag. Also note I'm testing including it as it is and with "data:image/jpeg;base64," appended.)

Any help very welcome!

Answer (score 0):

I discovered that the problem was with my base64 encoded string itself. When I generated the base64 using https://www.base64-image.de/, the file got sent without a problem. When I generated it using https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.3/libdoc/base64/rdoc/Base64.html, RNFetchBlob didn't send anything. I compared the two base64 strings, and the one generated by Ruby had lots of /n line breaks which weren't in the other version.

I have now learnt (via [Strange \n in base64 encoded string in Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2620975/strange-n-in-base64-encoded-string-in-ruby)) that to generate the base64 without the newlines, you need to call `strict_encode64` on `Base64` rather than `encode64`, which is what I was using.

Comment: Hi I have come across similar issue, where image is sent but not valid base64 image. What is the format you used for 'data' in final correct solution? Thanks in advance.